# sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: info

Tags: python, sql, flask

I am fresh to flask and was trying to build a server on my own, and I ran into an issue with SQLite operation error.

I did not make model.py (only running with app.py), do i have to make it?

Here's my code and Error

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_marshmallow import Marshmallow
import os
import json

app = Flask(__name__)
basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, 'crud.sqlite')
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
ma = Marshmallow(app)    

class Info(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    camId = db.Column(db.Integer, unique = False)
    location = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=False)
    isActive  = db.Column(db.Integer, unique = False)
    imgUrl = db.Column(db.String(120), unique= False)
    gender = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=False)
    age = db.Column(db.Integer, unique = False)

    def __init__(self, camId, location, isActive, imgUrl, gender, age):
        self.camId = camId
        self.location = location
        self.isActive = isActive
        self.imgUrl = imgUrl
        self.gender = gender
        self.age = age

class InfoSchema(ma.Schema):
    class Meta:
        fields = ('camId', 'location', 'isActive', 'imgUrl', 'gender', 'age')

info_schema = InfoSchema()
info_schemas = InfoSchema(many=True)


@app.route('/')
def base():
#    return (basedir)
    for jsonfile in os.listdir(basedir+"/dbex/"):
        if jsonfile[-4:] == "json":
            with open(basedir+"/dbex/"+jsonfile) as data_result:
                data = json.load(data_result)
                return jsonify(data)
        else:
            return 'Nothing found'


@app.route('/api/create/cameraData', methods =["POST"])
def create_cameraData():
    content = request.json
    camId = content["camId"]
    location = content["location"]
    isActive = content["isActive"]
    imgUrl = content["imgUrl"]
    gender = content["gender"]
    age = content["age"]

    new_data = Info(camId, location, isActive, imgUrl, gender, age)

    db.session.add(new_data)
    db.session.commit()

    return "success"


@app.route("/api/get/all", methods=["GET"])
def get_all_camera():
    all_camera = Info.query.all()
    result = info_schemas.dump(all_camera)
    return jsonify(result.data)
```

sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: info [SQL: 'SELECT info.id AS info_id, info."camId" AS "info_camId", info.location AS info_location, info."isActive" AS "info_isActive", info."imgUrl" AS "info_imgUrl", info.gender AS info_gender, info.age AS info_age \nFROM info'] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)

Comment: Is the table already created you're trying to access?

Comment: @SantoshKumar Yes I got crud.sqlite file in same directory

Comment: @Jinne if `crud.sqlite` is in directory it doesn't mean that table `info` was created. Run `db.create_all()` and restart app.